# I cant read file in my program in C++ using for loop in function

Tags: c++

Hi I have a problem with my program, it opens a file correctly in the `lineCounter` function, counts and throws the number of lines in the file to the console, but then in the `readFile` function it grinds something and then throws the error below. It seems to me that the problem lies in dynamic memory allocation, because when I did the same thing in the main function with local variables everything worked fine.

Console output:

[image: Console output]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void lineCounter(string);
void readFile(string);
string encryption(string);
string decryption(string);

int howMuch;
int linesOfFile;
string buffer;
string pathToFile;
string *fileContent = new string[linesOfFile];

int main()
{
    cout << "If your file is in the program folder enter the name itself with the extension. If it is not, give the full path." << endl;
    cin >> pathToFile;
    cin.ignore();

    lineCounter(pathToFile);
    cout << linesOfFile;
    readFile(pathToFile);
    cout << *fileContent << endl;


    delete [] fileContent;
    fileContent = NULL;
    return 0;
}
void lineCounter(string pathToFile)
{
    fstream file;
    file.open(pathToFile, ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        do
        {
            file >> buffer;
            linesOfFile++;

        }while(!file.eof());
        file.seekg(0);

        file.close();
        return;
    }
    else
        cout << "A critical error occurred" << endl;
    return;
}
void readFile(string pathToFile)
{
    fstream file;
    file.open(pathToFile, ios::in);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        /*int i =0;
        do
        {
            file >> fileContent[i]; // tutaj jakis bląd
            i++;

        }while(!file.eof());*/

        for(int i = 0; i < linesOfFile; i++)
        {
            file >> buffer;
            fileContent[i] = buffer;
        }
        file.seekg(0);

        file.close();
        return;
    }
    else
        cout << "A critical error occurred" << endl;
    return;
}
string encryption(string word)
{
    int asciiProtection;

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        asciiProtection = word[i] + howMuch;

        if(asciiProtection < 65)
            word[i] += (26 + howMuch);
        else if(asciiProtection > 90)
            word[i] -= (26 - howMuch);
        else
            word[i] += howMuch;
    }

    return word;
}
string decryption(string word)
{
    int asciiProtection;

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        asciiProtection = word[i] - howMuch;

        if(asciiProtection < 65)
            word[i] += (26 - howMuch);
        else if(asciiProtection > 90)
            word[i] -= (26 + howMuch);
        else
            word[i] -= howMuch;
    }

    return word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You allocate an array of size `0` here:

```
string *fileContent = new string[linesOfFile];
```

Reading `lineOfFile` afterwards from the user

```
cout << linesOfFile;
```

does not magically increase the size of the already allocated array. Any access to elements of that array, for example

```
fileContent[i] = buffer;
```

is out of bounds and causes undefined behavior.

---

TL;DR:

Use `std::vector` for dynamically sized arrays. It can resize when needed when you `push_back` more elements to it.

---

PS: There might be more issues in the code. One is `while(!file.eof());`. [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons?noredirect=1&lq=1). `file.eof()` as loop condition is wrong most of the time, because you need to read beyond the last entry before `file.eof()` returns `true`, hence your `linesOfFile` will be off by one.

Comment: It is not necessarily an empty array with 0 entries. linesOfFile is not initialised, so it could be any value, dependent of the compiler settings, isn't it?

Comment: @MiniMik `linesOfFile` is zero-initialized. It is a global